# Find and uninstall script

Tags: powershell

I have a script that does a search for the apps that I have in an array.

The idea is to find the app and silently uninstall it.

I have more than hours trying to understand why the last sentence doesn't work.

Can you help me? Please...!

Script:

```
########## Removing Apps ##########
$Appname =  @(
'Drafting Assistant'
)

Write-Host "Removing Apps" 
foreach ($App in $AppName) 
{
$App = Get-Itemproperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' |
Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, UninstallString, PSChildName |
Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match "^*$appname*"}
$UninstallString = if($App.Uninstallstring -match '^msiexec')
  {
  "$($App.UninstallString -replace '/I', '/X')"
  }
  else
  {
  $App.UninstallString
  }
Write-Verbose $UninstallString
Start-Process -FilePath cmd -ArgumentList "/v /qn /norestart", $UninstallString -NoNewWindow -Wait  
}
```

Thank you...

Comment: your `Start-Process` line doesn't make any sense to me. have you been able to build one manually that works? ///// also, take a look at `Get-Package -ProviderName MSI, Programs` and `Uninstall-Package`.

Comment: Have you read through **Working with Software Installations** <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-software-installations?view=powershell-7.2>

Comment: I'm afraid that `cmd` does not accept specified arguments. Check `cmd /?`…

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

I'll take I already have the routine to find the app but the uninstallation process is giving me an error.

If you can help me with that, I would appreciate it.

When I get the msi, I get this string:
MsiExec.exe / X {10a09cf8-8110-4895-8b79-73b9d4bc368e} / S / qn / norestart

As you can see, the problem is that there should ONLY be MsiExec.exe / x / S / qn / norestart

Any ideas?